# Given a record retrieve users authorized to :read it via cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I have a rails project using cancan for authorization. When a record is updated I want to notify users who are authorized to read it that the record is updated. Cancan easily lets me check if a specific user is authorized to perform an action on a record or get retrieve records that the specific user is allowed to operate on. But can I do the reverse through cancan? I.e. given a specific record retrieve all users authorized to perform an action on it?

Comment: You can just call can `:read` ability on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am averagely familiar with Cancan. Having said that, this is what I could think of:

```
@myrecord = MyRecord.find(1)

authorized_user_ids = User.find_each do |user|
  user.id if Ability.new(user).can? :read, @myrecord
end.compact

puts authorized_user_ids
# => [1, 2, 5, 10, 78]
```

Note however, this is extremely inefficient because it will loop through all users. You might want to perform caching this with a separate table/model that you would implement.

Answer (score 0):

> given a specific record retrieve all users authorized to perform an action on it?

No.

That's like asking *"can Devise show me all the users who are currently logged in?"* - it doesn't have the capacity to do it because the scope is not there.

---

There are several ways to achieve what you want.

The simplest is to push the notification (I'm not sure how you're doing this) to the front-end of your application (so that, potentially, *anyone* could read it).

Then, as `CallmeSurge` said, you'll be able to use `can? read` on it to make it so that only the users who were eligible could actually invoke the data:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= [[notification]] if can? :read, [[notification]] %>
```

--

The other way is to use ActiveRecord to return the users eligible to read the notification with the criteria you use already. This can be done using the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.notify
      where(x: y)
   end
end
```

Then you'd be able to set the notifications as follows:

```
User.notify.each do |user|
   user.notification.create .....
end
```